# Wrong display when running an Android project?

Tags: java, android

I have imported 7 different projects with Android Studio 2.8

1. google map project
2. take a photo project
3. TennisDemo game project
4. JSONUploader
5. JSONDownloader
6. AndroidServerDemo
7. Download HTML

At the first time the execution doesn't run the 7th project, but after changing the version of  the gradle of each project from gradle 2.8 to gradle 2.10 the error of the execution has disappeared.

Nevertheless, in the display of the execution there is a problem: the display of the execution of all the seven projects is the same of the first project, which mean that only the first project is displaying its execution for the rest of the 7 project also, not only its own.

The problem isn't in any of the seven projects, because I've downloaded them all from a tutorial from Udemy.

I want to run them all, not only the seventh.

Comment: From my experience: don't mix unrelated modules on the same project. Make a project for each "project", where all modules are related somehow (usually libraries/resources/dependencies). This said, you need to create a specific Run configuration for each module to be able to run the one you want.

Answer (score 3):

Hey I am assuming all the projects are under the same workspace ... if that is correct then you just need to select which project you want to build from the top menu.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POlip.png)

Comment: Sorry, how may i select project i want to build from the top menu.?
thank you.